# Setting configuration file with Log4j using slf4j-log4j12

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I know there is several answers for how to set the file. Non have worked with me.

I'm trying to unifying several conf files for that I need to set the conf of log4j provided in slf4j-log4j12 into the configuration file provided as parameter of the program. Till now I tried by setting as parameter of the jvm like:

`java '-Dlog4j.configuration=conf.cfg' -jar my.jar`

I'm getting back:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j:ERROR Could not parse file [].
```

Setting programatically by:

```
 System.setProperty("log4j.configuration",(new File(  Configurator.getDefaultConfig().getString(Const.LoggingDefaultLoggingFile))).toURL().toString());
```

and

```
 System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",(new File(  Configurator.getDefaultConfig().getString(Const.LoggingDefaultLoggingFile))).toURL().toString());
```

Same result.

I tried using `DOMConfigurator` but is for `xml` I'm using `properties` so no success.

I was searching how to reload the log4j but the give complex solution for making subscription for monitoring change and constant loading of changes.

I just want programatically change the configuration file **once**.

Till now, I was able to set the file just if I put it directly into the jar. But this by using a separated file with the default name.

Is there a way of loading the file directly int the Log4j (no shity system properties)? o there is a simple way of doing this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. log4j looking for `log4j.properties` under `WEB-INF\classes`
2. [PropertyConfigurator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) class,

example of usage:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
// ...
public static final Logger log=Logger.getLogger(App.class);
// ...
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Comment: first get the logger and then chnage it?